# Disable Azure diagnostic agent for Azure VM diagnostic logs using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, azure-vm-templates

We have managed to get the diagnostic extension installed using quick start ARM template [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-diagnostics-extension-windows) and it appears to be working fine, however is there any way to keep it turned off while provisioning so that it does not start pushing collected data to storage sink unless it is explicitly enabled manually later whenever needed e.g. using Azure portal?

[image]

Use case is - we would want to spin up several Azure VMs using ARM template with diagnostic settings extension added but disabled, it would only be enabled for select VMs later if required. Is it possible to achieve using ARM template?

Comment: You can simply check the template generated by the portal and figure this setting out.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gaurav, yep that's the first thing we tried but appears that portal does not reflect / add any specific tag / property to the extension definition in JSON when it is disabled and so the template looks same.

Comment: and it also appears that it cannot be disabled with Az commands too.. can anyone confirm?

Comment: setting it to disabled doesnt work for me

Comment: Do you try to set the enable property as false in [`diagnosticsProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2019-07-01/virtualmachines#virtualmachineproperties-object) of the VM?

Comment: What about the situation now? Do you solve the problem with the suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for the response, was referring this link to enable the diagnostics on the VMs (using VMDiagnosticsSettings extension) as mentioned in the link here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-template#add-the-azure-diagnostics-extension-to-the-vm-resource-definition
Can you please share where exactly the flag needs to be set there?

Comment: The property is used in the VM template, not in the extension. When you install the extension, it means you would enable it in the VM.

Comment: yup that's the challenge, we want to add the diagnostics extension to the VM and just configure it by pointing to the correct storage account (which is working) but keep the diagnostics infrastructure logs settings in disabled state (the setting highlighted in the picture above) which does not seem possible currently. The diagnosticProfile object which you are referring in the VM ARM template, appears to point bootDiagnostics which is something we are not trying to configure.